# How to add the return value of multiple methods in a different method (python)

Tags: python, oop

```
import random
colors = ['brown','black','yellow', 'green','purple','golden','white','pink']
breeds = ['lab','border collie','dalmation','husky','chiauaua']
sizes = ['small','medium','large']

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, color, breed, size):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.size = size
    
    def rate_color(self):
        for index, color in enumerate(colors):
            if self.color == color:
                color_rating = abs(index - len(colors)) / len(colors)
                return color_rating
    def rate_breed(self):
        for index, breed in enumerate(breeds):
            if self.breed == breed:
                breed_rating = abs(index - len(breeds)) / len(breeds)
                return breed_rating
    def rate_size(self):
        for index, size in enumerate(sizes):
            if self.size == size:
                size_rating = abs(index - len(sizes)) / len(sizes)
                return size_rating
    def final_rate(self):
        final_rating = (self.rate_size + self.rate_breed + self.rate_color) * 33
        return final_rating
  
dog1 = Dog(random.choice(colors),random.choice(breeds),random.choice(sizes))
print(dog1.color)
print(dog1.rate_color())
print(dog1.breed)
print(dog1.rate_breed())
print(dog1.size)
print(dog1.rate_size())

print(dog1.final_rate())
```

This code produces the error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'method'
```

I know it is a problem with the `final_rate` method but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: you forgot the `()` to call the method: `self.rate_size()` & co

Comment: Please use backticks (`\`\`\``) instead of single quotes (`'''`) to properly format your code for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks lol, this is my first time using stack overflow and I am shocked on how quickly I got a response. is there a way to directly respond to your response?

Comment: @whm33 you basically just did, for something more direct use `@username`  where `username` is well... the username in this case seemingly `@spicy.dll` is what you are looking for. anyways, the issue is that you have to call those methods using `()`